# Nokogiri example not showing array (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

When I try to run this via terminal I can parse/display the data but when I type in pets_array = []

I am not seeing anything

My code is as follows:

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'JSON'
require 'Pry'
require 'csv'

page = HTTParty.get('https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/pet?s=0')

parse_page = Nokogiri::HTML(page)

pets_array = []

parse_page.css('.content').css('.row').css('.result-title hdrlnk').map do |a|
  post_name = a.text
  pets_array.push(post_name)
end

CSV.open('pets.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << pets_array
end

Pry.start(binding)
```

Comment: `$('.row')` doesn't show any elements on that page in the browser console

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to be precise you could access each anchor tag with class `.result-title.hdrlnk` inside `.result-info`, `.result-row`, `.rows` and `.content`:

```
page = HTTParty.get 'https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/pet?s=0'
parse_page = Nokogiri::HTML page
pets_array = parse_page.css('.content .rows .result-row .result-info .result-title.hdrlnk').map &:text
p pets_array
# ["Mini pig", "Black Russian Terrier", "2 foster or forever homes needed Asap!", ...]
```

As you're using map, you can use the `pets_array` variable to store the text on each iterated element, no need to push.

If you want to write the data stored in the array, then you can push is directly, no need to redefined as an empty array (the reason because you get a blank csv file):

```
require 'httparty'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

page = HTTParty.get 'https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/pet?s=0'
parse_page = Nokogiri::HTML page
pets_array = parse_page.css('.content .rows .result-row .result-info .result-title.hdrlnk').map &:text
CSV.open('pets.csv', 'w') { |csv| csv << pets_array }
```

Comment: Thank you....is the above "all" that is needed? Could you paste the entire re-vise of my code? I tried the above but was thrown errors...I can play around with it a bit if needed.

Comment: The working code is [here](https://gist.github.com/vnhnhm/8326c20da01b582c033de6ca154fbabf), I've omitted the CSV part.